# Spring Data R2DBC Persist Nested Attributes

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

I've got a `List<Order>` (or `Flux<Order>` if I wanted) where each `Order` element has a `List<Item>`. I want to persist this object hierarchy into two tables of a relational database using `spring-data-r2dbc` (and therefore `ReactiveCrudRepository`) and `spring-webflux`. These two tables have a foreign key constraint, so an `Order` must be inserted *before* its `Item`s.

Transaction handling is yet another topic and out of scope of this question. The return type of that part of the application should be a `Flux<Order>` again, as it'll be the return value of a REST response.

The question is how to "combine" a `Mono<Order>` and its `Flux<Item>`.

I've looked into zipping but I couldn't get it to work (see commented out code below). Also I'm quite sure that zipping isn't the right thing anyway as I have *one* on one side and *n* on the other. I also tried `.doOnSuccess`, but that also leaves the `Flux<Item>` without a terminal operation.

### SomeService.kt

```
fun saveOrders(orders: List<Order>): Flux<Order> {
    // the flatMap (and flatMapMany below) with side effect isn't that nice either
    return Flux.fromIterable(orders).flatMap { saveOrder(it) }
}

private fun saveOrder(order: Order): Mono<Order> {
    val soonToBeSavedOrder: Mono<Order> = orderRepository.save(order)

    val soonTeBeSavedItems: Flux<Item> = soonToBeSavedOrder.flatMapMany { saveItems(it) }

    // TODO: how to "combine" the Mono and the Flux because the Flux doesn't
    // have a terminal operation that way and therefore saveItems is never called.

    return soonToBeSavedOrder
}

private fun saveItems(order: Order): Flux<Item> {
    return itemRepository.saveAll(order.items)
}
```

### Order.kt

```
class Order(
    id: UUID,
    var someData: String,
    @Transient
    val items: MutableList<Item> = ArrayList()) : Persistable<UUID> {

    @Id
    private var id: UUID = id

    override fun getId(): UUID { return id }
    override fun isNew(): Boolean { return true }

}
```

### Item.kt

```
class Item(
    id: UUID,
    var someData: String) : Persistable<UUID> {

    @Id
    private var id: UUID = id

    override fun getId(): UUID? { return id }
    override fun isNew(): Boolean { return true }

}
```